# Create a load of button images from .jpg files

Tags: python, button, wxpython, wxwidgets

I have a folder containing a number of `.jpg` files (each of them are 100x100 pixels).

I would like to create a `wxPython` panel showing all these `.jpg` (with a mosaic layout) as `wx.BitmapButton`.

I tried with the wxPython's demo called `BitmapButton.py` but this loads images from embedded image only, here I don't know what's the canonical way to do it with JPEGs.

Moreover, I would like this panel to automatically give a **good** disposition of the buttons.

*Example : let's assume I have 10 buttons.*

- *If window's width is large enough to fit 5 buttons per row, 2 rows of 5 buttons should be displayed,*
- *If the window is resized to a smaller width, then 2 rows of 4 buttons + 1 row of 2 buttons should be displayed, etc.*

**How to deal with JPEGs in** `wx.BitmapButton`, **and if many buttons, how to make that they have automatically a good layout in the panel (auto alignement in rows) ?**

[image]

Comment: All of my wxPython experience tells me that re-arranging the buttons based on the size is going to be a massive pain

Comment: Thanks for your answer @wnnmaw. My question was indeed : is there a `BoxSizer` widget (or whatever other name) that could handle the *automatic*-arranging of the buttons in the panel ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is a new sizer that can do what you want in wxPython 2.9+ called WrapSizer. There is an example of its usage in the wxPython demo. You can also read about it at the following:

- http://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/WrapSizer.html

As for the BitmapButton, I am pretty sure you can pass it a jpg file if you do it properly. You will probably need to do something like this:

```
img = wx.Image(filepath, wx.BITMAP_TYPE_ANY)
bmp = wx.BitmapFromImage(img)
b = wx.BitmapButton(self, -1, bmp, (20, 20),
                   (bmp.GetWidth()+10, bmp.GetHeight()+10))
```

Comment: Great! I did not expected it was so simple... Two small little things : what's the simpler way to add shadow to the bitmaps (like the ablum art here : http://static.pcinpact.com/images/bd/news/119801.jpeg)  and how to add text below the image *which would be part of the button (ie clickable) too* ?

Comment: I don't know about the shadow...you may have to add that to the image itself somehow. Or maybe create a shadow image and combine it with the bitmap before applying it to the button. As for adding text, the BitmapButton doesn't appear to support that. You might be able to get that to work with the GenBitmapButton though.

Comment: Thank you @MikeDriscoll. When the buttons don't fit in the current window, the last buttons are resized to smaller (which I don't want, I would prefer that a scrollbar is added then) : http://pastebin.com/Jq5Sp296
Do you have an idea on that ?

Comment: Moreover, I noticed, when making 10 `BitmapButtons` (size 150x150) + `WrapSizer`, there is lots of flickering when I resize the window. Any idea for this @MikeDriscoll ?

Comment: Maybe use a ScrolledPanel or ScrolledWindow, although that might prevent the wrapping you want. For removing flickering, I would look at the Freeze/Thaw methods for the panel.